# Should I keep my AdMob Publisher ID secret?

Tags: android, github, admob

I'm publishing an app on the Android Market which has an ad in it.  I've also been keeping the app's source in a public github repository.  In the app, I have the line:

```
ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
```

where MY_AD_UNIT_ID is my actual publisher ID.  Is there anything malicious anyone could do with my publisher ID?  Is there any reason I would want to keep this secret?

Comment: While I think Matt's advice (below) is probably good, I think it's worth noting that anyone can get the publisher id used in an app simply by watching for the Tag "Ads" in the LogCat.  It's listed as "slotname".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, there probably isn't anything malicious that someone could do with your publisher ID, but in order to create an Admob account and get a Publisher ID, a user has to accept the Admob [Terms of Use](http://www.admob.com/home/terms).  By making your Publisher ID publicly available, theoretically someone could bypass the acceptance of Admob's Terms of Use and this may have legal implications.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and the text written here should not be considered legal advice and/or used as such.